# Renaming sub folders of sub folders with simple .bat

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder that has 1000 folders all with different customer names. In each customers folder is a file named fp1. I want to change the fp1 to pic in every folder. I saw an example that would change each sub folder to a different name... ren "fp1" "Pics"... and just run it as a .bat . In this case  Folder/different names/fp1 want all fp1 to be pics.
Thanks

Comment: No, That is why I need help

Answer (score 0):

From the prompt,

```
for /r "c:\your\directory\with\1000\subdirectories" %x in (fp1) do @if exist "%x" echo ren "%x" "pic"
```

This will show the files that would be renamed. Remove the `echo` keyword to actually rename the files.